# Maven run / debug configurations: what to put to command line to get Hello world to run

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a simple hello world program written in Java in IntelliJ IDEA. My problem is trying to run it. I can't find simple instructions what to put in the configuring settings to run.

Before putting in the Maven attempt there was no option to use any default running. Even pressing Shift F10 didn't do anything. I put some Maven version up based on one YouTube video and now trying to automatically run gives error. I think I have the working directory set right, but I put for the command line part `spring.boot:run` and this is causing problems. Error on automatically and manually running is the same: `No plugin found for prefix 'spring.boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups` .

What can I put on the commandline part to make it work?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Go View->Tool Buttons, select tool buttons. It will give maven project at right side. Open window and click on + icon, select pom.xml. It will download all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn package && java -jar target/{artifactId}-{version}.jar
```

your artifactId and version will be defined at your pom.xml

share your code, if you are trying to learn or do your first java projects with maven you can use File> New Project> Maven.

If you want to use spring boot then try to follow https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ and if you have some problem following the tutorial share the logs (with errors that you are getting), your code and the step that you were following.